# Operations with summatory from $ \sum_{i,j} $ to $ \sum_{i>j} $ help please.

Tags: analysis, summation

How can I prove that

$$ \sum_{i,j} \frac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}} = \sum_{i>j} \frac{(\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}-1)(\sqrt{a_i}-\sqrt{a_j})^{2}(\sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_j})}{(1+a_i)(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}} $$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_{ij}:=\tfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}}$ so $A_{ii}=0$ and$$\sum_{ij}A_{ij}=\sum_{i\ne j}A_{ij}=\sum_{i>j}(A_{ij}+A_{ji})=\sum_{i>j}(a_i-a_j)\left(\tfrac{1}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}}-\tfrac{1}{(1+a_i)\sqrt{a_j}}\right),$$reducing the problem to$$(1+a_i)\sqrt{a_j}-(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}=(\sqrt{a_ia_j}-1)(\sqrt{a_i}-\sqrt{a_j}).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how exactly does that works? Why would you subtract A_ij - A_ji and put i>j, what does that mean?

Comment: @MCuadros Small typo fixed.

Comment: Alright; however, I am not an expert, could you provide me with a brief explanation of what approach you did there? Just to know

Comment: @MCuadros In general $\sum_{i\ne j}=\sum_{i>j}(A_{ij}+A_{ji})$, e.g. because both sides comprise $n^2-n=2\binom{n}{2}$ terms including both of $A_{21},\,A_{12}$.